# Unable to see Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with my Tab Activity. I can't see anything, like literally nothing. I already changed the `style.xml` of the activity but it still doesn't work out.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my `style.xml`

```xml
<resources>

   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

   <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you change the theme from Dialog to AppTheme on the Preview Window?

Comment: Could you please share your activity xml file also?

Comment: Actually I already tried to do it again and again to different projects but it ends up that my activity for the tab activity is always empty.

Comment: @AytekSökmen, I already tried that and other ways, I even tried to clean project, but nothing still happens.